# Print AVL tree in columns

Tags: c, tree, printf, binary-tree

I'm implementing AVL trees in C and I want to print all the elements of the tree in three columns in the console.

I have this:

```
void printInOrder(nodo * raiz) {
    if (raiz != NULL) {
        printInOrder(raiz->esq);
        printf("%s\n", raiz->codigo);
        printInOrder(raiz->dir);
    }
}
```

Anyone knows how to print the output in three columns?

Comment: What goes in column 1, column 2, column 3?  Please show a sample tree (perhaps 7-8 nodes) and the expected output.  As it stands, there isn't a simple way to answer your question.

Comment: If you have something like this:

`code`
   String 1
   /    \
String 2  String 3  
 /      \
String 4 String 5

You will end up with:

String 4
String 2
String 5
String 1
String 3

What I want is:

String 4  String 5  String 3
String 2  String 1

Comment: Please add the info to the question where you can format it sowe have a chance of understanding what you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was searching for:

```
int printInOrder(nodo *root, int count){
if(root!=NULL){
    count=printInOrder(root->left,count);
    count++;
    if(count%PRINT_COLS==0 && count!=0) printf("%s \n", root->code);
    else printf("%s \t\t", root->code);
    if(count%(2*10*PRINT_COLS)==0 && count!=0){getch();}
    count=printInOrder(root->right, count);
}
return count;
```

}